# Windows Server 2012 R2 VDI Naming Suffix Length

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hostname, vdi

With a 2012 R2 deployment, when I create a pooled VDI collection, I have to specify a prefix and a suffix.

All of our other machines have names of the format;

```
FLX-RDSH-V001
```

The FLX is the location code, the RDSH is the role/service/purpose of the machine, V indicates virtual, and the number is just the number.

With a VDI collection, I can create a prefix of

```
FLX-VDI-
```

But the suffix number seems to be of a set format. It only looks to go from 1 to 9, then it switches to 2 digits and becomes 10 - 99, then becomes 3 digits etc.

Is there a way to set the number format of the suffix to a constant 3 digit length, so that it will use 001 - 009, then 010 - 099, then 100 - 999?

Comment: The first VM should be 100, that's the only solution I see

Comment: That's unfortunate :(